# Why my psql (postgreSQL) not inserting the email and password

Tags: postgresql, insert, cryptography, psql, pgcrypto

I've created a table using the following code and I'm encrypting the password using bf.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
CREATE TABLE auth (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  dob DATE NOT NULL,
  email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

After this If i try to INSERT the data using the following -:

```
INSERT INTO auth (name, dob, email, password) VALUES (
  'Divyansh'
  '1995-09-21'
  'divyanshkumar@gmail.com',
  crypt('password', gen_salt('bf'))
);
```

> I got error "**INSERT has more target columns than expressions**"

[image]

Comment: You are missing commas in the `VALUES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are missing commas after each value:

```
INSERT INTO auth (name, dob, email, password) VALUES (
'Divyansh', # <--- comma here
'1995-09-21', # <--- comma here
'divyanshkumar@gmail.com',
crypt('password', gen_salt('bf'))
);
```

It does point that there's more `targets` than `expression`, it effectively sees 2 values without commas.

See if that works.